# Auto-fold multi-line css in React

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components, emotion

Extensions like Tailwind Fold automatically fold inline css to improve readability, but they only apply to single-liners.

I use libraries like emotion or styled-components to write multi-line css. I want this:

```js
 function Component() {
    return (
        <div className={css`
            display: flex;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            margin: 0;
        `}/>
    )
}
```

to automatically turn into:

```js
 function Component() {
    return (
        <div className=.../> // fold multi-lines automatically
    )
}
```

Are there any extensions or built-in vscode settings that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: not sure about any extensions, but have you considered using an external stylesheet. But if you want inline style I would recommend tailwind css. There is an extension for vscode, [Tailwind Fold](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stivo.tailwind-fold) that will collapse the className.

Comment: @cqb13 external stylesheets require me to go searching and require twice as many files per major component. Tailwind is one-line only which gets bad for readability, and you have to repeatedly declare pseudo-selectors like `:hover` for multiple alterations. Multi-line CSS, embedded in the JSX itself, hidden but viewable on click like the Tailwind Fold extension, would be the best of both worlds.

Comment: Did a quick search on vs code marketplace and found this extension [classname fold](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Hamidk.classname-fold). Not sure if it does what you want but you can try. if it does not work let me know, and I can make a extension to do it.

Comment: @cqb13 Unfortunately that collapses the entire component structure (If I have <ParentDiv> containing <ChildDiv>, collapsing className will hide <ChildDiv>. It's equivalent to folding the top-level div, hiding all nested divs. I only want to hide the CSS styling, while still able to see the JSX component hierarchy.